# When setting Default: Disabled on a form, some Boolean options get disabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have the following line that generates a form. When called, the controller sets @disabled to true in some cases, false in others.

```
= simple_form_for [:applicant, @application ],defaults: { disabled: @disabled }, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f|
```

On some pages, I have a select statement that uses boolean options.

```
= f.input :accommodation, as: :select, collection: yes_no
```

That calls the following helper function as a collection

```
  def yes_no
[
  ['Yes', true ],
  ['No', false ]
]
end
```

When @disabled is set to false, and simple_form goes to render the false option, it seems to disable it. I'm unsure how to get around this boolean-fighting to generate both the true and false options in the drop down, while also allowing for @disabled to disable the entire form (when applicable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue between SimpleForm and Rails: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1257

tonywok's answer seems to be a valid workaround for now: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1257#issuecomment-119226834

Change

```
= simple_form_for [:applicant, @application ],defaults: { disabled: @disabled }, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f|
```

To

```
= simple_form_for [:applicant, @application ],defaults: { disabled: @disabled, readonly: nil }, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f|
```